# JQuery reference rewuired

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-plugins, javascript

There is a flash element on homepage of this website [Click here](http://cdl.tv/)!. I want to create similar kind of effect with jQuery. Please suggest how could I do that? or any library available for it.

Comment: it will be a difficult job trying to do it in jquery

Comment: Yes. But I just want the motion effect! 
I means the way objects are moving with mouse movement. I don't want sounds and other animation all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples/tutorials in web for mouse movements etc. Hope these help you in achieving the goal.

http://progtuts.info/186/create-a-parallax-website-header/

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jparallax

http://www.shinyface.com/2010/09/04/simple-parallax-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different plugins for this effect. Although not with the sound.

It would be pretty tough to do something like this if you have no experience with jquery or javascript.

[mouse driven parallax](http://www.greepit.com/2011/06/implement-a-mouse-driven-parallax-effect-with-jquery-plax/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kolby! I just want movements not the sounds!!! THanks!! ;)